# How to bounty an answer when the questions and answers in Community Wiki mode?

Tags: support, bounties, community-wiki

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

As is well known, in Community Wiki posts, all users will not earn any reputation.
But if I start a bounty on a Community Wiki question (its answers are Community Wiki too), then I give the bounty to an answer which has been edited by more than 1 user, who will get the bounty reputation?

Comment: anyone can answer the question?

Comment: Please check out the [Bounty FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work), which explains that bounties are completely unaffected (properly now, at any rate) by Community Wiki status. The bounty will be awarded to the author of the post regardless of the number of editors, just like with a non-Community Wiki post.

Comment: Why would you want to award a bounty to CW? About what question are we talking?